# In android Programmatically how to check the condition I have enough amount to send SMS?

Tags: android

In android Programmatically how to check the condition I have enough amount to send SMS?And what are the corner cases consider while sending sms using smsManager in android code,example Network availability,Sim card status etc..

Comment: You mean enough *money?* Surely it's best to just try it, and handle the error that results?

Comment: ya money.I am having 0 balance, my app wait until recharge the prepaid account then only send the text message,which stored in sharedpreferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way what you wanted to do.. better you handle errors. That may be more appropriate way.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about enough credits/balance to send SMS, then no, there's no way to do that except try sending the SMS and see if it sends or fails.

There are some carriers (like in the Philippines for example) who has this network api to retrieve balance for a customer, but it's either not available for public, or the access is through a Rest Server (requires the phone to have data connection).

Comment: if the sms send to fails means i want to make it a background running service wait to send sms.For that how to do it in service?.